# How to properly log one off changes in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I've started using `Ansible` for server configuration. I store Ansible-related files in a `git` repository and it works perfectly.

My question is: what are the approaches to logging one-off tasks run with Ansible. For example, when deleting old users accounts, do I run a single task that deletes the accounts, or do I include the `user=john state=absent line` in my `site.yml`.

Is there a best-practice about this? If I include it in my `site.yml` it will keep increasing. If I run it as one-off task, other members of the team are not aware that this task has been run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vars/users.yml i would have a list of users that you want to be available and a list of users that are no longer required. You now have versioned source code of the state of your users.

The following is untested

```
---
users:
  active:
    - jon
    - sansa
    - arya
  legacy:
    - ned
    - joffrey
```

Then your plays will look like ...

```
- name: add active users
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{users['active']}}"

- name remove legacy users
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{users['legacy']}}"
```

Once you know that `joffrey` is long gone (do you?) then you can remove him from the legacy list so you're not ensuring he isn't there seasons after he left your organisation.

He'll still be there in version control so you can always refer to when he was added and removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a couple of tasks to your playbook to delete unnecessary users:

```
- shell: "getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 900 {print $1}' | grep -v nobody"
  register: passwd_res
  changed_when: false

- user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ passwd_res.stdout_lines | difference(required_users) }}"
```

Given that `required_users` is a list of users to be present, we get all users present on target system with UID>900 except `nobody`, and make sure that users that are present but not required are deleted.